# Mongoose select error

Tags: mongoose

I have a mongoose schema which is like this

```
    first_name          : String,
    other_names         : String,
    last_name           : String,
    gender              : String,
    title               : String,
employment      :{
        office              : String,
        location            : String
    },
    hobbies         :[{
        hobbied_id          : Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }],
    contact     :[{
        address             : String,
        city                : String
    }]
```

when i try to extract information from the mongodb through mongoose i used

```
Person.find({'exployment.office':'Greenway'})
    .exec(function(err, result){
        console.log(result);//<- this gives expected result 
        console.log(result.employment.office);//<- this produces error of undefined
        console.log(result.contact.address);//<- this produces error
    });
```

This produces all the information relating to all the people working in Greenway.
But when I try to get specific details from the result it produces error of undefined
Please what am i doing wrong and also is there any book or site that is useful for learning mongooose

Comment: is the result a string or a json ?

Comment: can you post the result of this line: `console.log(result);`?